# Get resource identifier (resId) of multiple images from asset or raw folder to an int array

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-assets

I have 100+ images to load into a `listView`, and I am trying to store all the `resId` into an `int[]`. I can done it from `drawable` by using the below code

```
Field[] ID_Fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
        resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++)
        {
            try {

                resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But my problem is that I don't need all images in the `drawable` folder for my `listView`. So can i create a folder inside the `asset` and get all `resId` into a `int[]` ? or can I use `raw` folder for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you exactly want. question is not clear enough

Comment: Are you asking for suggestion or code?

Comment: if I am use the above code, i will get all the images resId into the array.. Actually I dont need that,, It is little big project and so the drawable contains other designing and background images also. I only wants some of drawable images into the listview. and also we cant create folder inside the drawable. So I am trying to use asset folder

Comment: Or can i use raw folder instead of drawable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

YES we can do it. Copy the images into res/`raw` folder and try with this code

```
Field[] ID_Fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
        resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++)
        {

            try {
                resArray[i]= ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

After that resArray contains the resId of the images in the `raw` folder

Answer (score 0):

It is possible..but It is not a good way for you. You can put images in Asset folder
Like this [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175250/android-when-is-it-appropriate-to-store-images-in-the-assets-rather-than-the-dr)

but if you do this there can be issues created
[Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788519/is-it-possible-to-save-image-in-assets-folder-from-application)

So now it is up to you how you use it. :)