# how to add drawable all images in array in android programmatically

Tags: java, android, image, function, android-drawable

I have a code that let me use images in drawable folder, but all the images  are stored in array by name-

I wanna load them programmatically by a function and store them in array

this is the array :

```java
private int[] theBitmapIds = { R.drawable.elefant_001, R.drawable.elefant_002, R.drawable.elefant_003, R.drawable.elefant_004,
R.drawable.elefant_005, R.drawable.elefant_006, R.drawable.elefant_007,
R.drawable.elefant_008, R.drawable.elefant_009, R.drawable.elefant_010,
R.drawable.elefant_011, R.drawable.elefant_012, R.drawable.elefant_013,
R.drawable.elefant_014, R.drawable.elefant_015, R.drawable.elefant_016,
R.drawable.elefant_017, R.drawable.elefant_018, R.drawable.elefant_019,
R.drawable.elefant_020, R.drawable.elefant_021,R.drawable.elefant_022,
R.drawable.elefant_022, R.drawable.elefant_023,R.drawable.elefant_024,
R.drawable.elefant_025, R.drawable.elefant_026, R.drawable.elefant_027,
R.drawable.elefant_028, R.drawable.elefant_029, R.drawable.elefant_030,
R.drawable.elefant_031, R.drawable.elefant_032, R.drawable.elefant_033,
R.drawable.elefant_034, R.drawable.elefant_035, R.drawable.elefant_036,
R.drawable.elefant_037, R.drawable.elefant_038, R.drawable.elefant_039,
R.drawable.elefant_040};
```

I changed it by the function

```java
public int [] theBitmapIds( ) {
    Field[] ID_Fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
    int[] theBitmapIds = new int[ID_Fields.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {
        try {
            theBitmapIds[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt( null );
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return  theBitmapIds;
}

private int[] theBitmapIds=theBitmapIds( );
```

but when I call the array in other function, it still has nothing in it

```java
public Bitmap getBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(theBitmapIds[index]);

        int margin = 1;
        int border = 1;
        Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

        int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
        int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
            imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
            imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                    / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }
```

I am confused especially I'm a noob in java. How I can make this code work by editing the function or by change this line of code:

```java
private int[] theBitmapIds=theBitmapIds( );
```

or

```java
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(theBitmapIds[index]);
```

Someone help me pls!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AssetManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager) to directly load assets with their paths.

You can get its instance by calling `context.getAssets()`.

With it's `open()` method, you'll be able to get an `InputStream` for that asset.

Then you can use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to convert it into `Bitmap`.

Comment: use AssetManager to directly load assets with their paths. i tried it but don't work 
out of memory error !

Comment: You will get out of memory error if you load a bitmap that is too large for the device to handle. **Large** means the size of the image file in bytes. I don't know the size of your image, but you have many bitmaps to load at once which might throw that error. Best way is to use smaller images.

Comment: problem resolved, i used over 300 png with large size , thank you !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433093/get-resource-identifier-resid-of-multiple-images-from-asset-or-raw-folder-to-a